# Scroll Bar Issues

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am having an issue with scrolling. For some reason in chrome there is a whole bunch of white space at the bottom of the page. (This does not appear in firefox, I don't have IE installed.

Here is a link to the code I'm looking at: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1990107/vertical.html

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
<style>
.report{
  width:800px;
  height:1036px;
}

.report-container{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width:800px;
}
#select-account{
  margin-left:-50px;
  background:blue;
  width:50px;
  float:left;
  height:100px;
}
</style>
</head> 
<body> 
<div class='report-container'>
 <div id='select-account'>content</div>
 <img class='report' src='http://placekitten.com/g/800/1036'/>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I have the described gap in Chrome dev, but not IE8, Firefox, Safari. How odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `position:absolute;` to your `#select-account{}` 

 See fix here: http://jsfiddle.net/htNrn/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding...

white-space: nowrap;

to you report-container css class

This works as far as I can see in all browsers

Cheers

Justin